# What does cavity look like on X ray?

Tags: coloration-discoloration, tooth-decay, x-rays, cavity

[image]

Can someone tell me how to spot a cavity on this image?

What I have found so far is that it is supposed to be darker area. But I have trouble recognizing it in real x ray image.

Comment: Wisdom tooth coming in on the lower left? (I'm just curious, this isn't where I think the cavity is or anything)

Comment: @L.B. Most probable. The one on the upper left has either already been removed or cannot be seen on this x-ray...

Comment: It's pretty obvious once you see it. Bottom row, second tooth from the front, at the gum line.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom row, second from the front, right at the gum line.

[image]

See the darkened wedge-shaped area on the right edge of the tooth in the enlargement below? That is exactly what it looks like: a hole in the enamel of the tooth. That is what a cavity is and it's what it looks like on x-ray.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a specialist but I notice something at the top of the 4th tooth from the top side. Maybe there's the cavity

Comment: I, too, have no idea what I'm talking about, but noticed the same thing.